# relative url not workin in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

the problem im having is when is when i click on a link or button on the site which has a relative url i get a 404 error because it sets the link to the root

ex

i have my router setup like:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'views/home/main',
'views/projects/list',
'views/users/list'
], function($, _, Backbone, mainHomeView, projectListView, userListView ){

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
   routes: {
       'projects': 'showProjects',
       'users': 'showUsers',
       '*actions': 'defaultAction'
    },
  initialize: function(){
        this.home = new mainHomeView.homeView(this);
        this.user = new userListView.userView(this);
        this.project = new projectListView.projectView(this);
  },
  showProjects: function(){
        this.project.render();
  },

    showUsers: function(){
        this.user.render();
    },
    defaultAction: function(actions){
        this.home.render()
    }
});

var initialize = function(){
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start();
};

return {
    initialize: initialize
};
});
```

and my buttons/links are set like :

```
 <ul>
      <li><a href="#/links">Links</a></li>
 </ul>
```

so if my url is: www.some-web-site.com/example/ex1/

and i click the link it should set the url to:
www.some-web-site.com/example/ex1/#/links

instead i get: 404 not found - www.some-web-site.com/links

am i missing something? thanks

Comment: Something is wrong with this _link_, it looks like it is ignoring the '#'. Are you sure there is not any _typo_ in your real code?

Comment: thanks @fguillen i think thats exactly what its doing, its ignoring the #, ive checked through everything and i cant seem to find any typos

Comment: Check no JavaScript is modifying this element, also that no one is catching the `onclick` event on it.. Also check what the server is receiving and what is doing with the `request` maybe it is making some `redirection`.

Comment: Try this - `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})`.